# Keep drop down option on the next page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 3 pages: `index.php`, `soldc.php` and `soldf.php` like in select option below.
On each page i have the same dropdown as header. So when i click the button , depending on dropown option, the button redirect to soldc.php or sodf.php where are displayed different information. I want to keep dropdown option selected on the next page i'm redirected by the button. Thx for help.

```html
<html>
  <body>
<form name="hop"><br>
<p align="center">
<select name="choose" style="width: 168px;height: 35px;">
<option value="./soldc.php">Sold clienti</option>
<option value="./soldf.php">Sold furnizori</option>
</select>
<input type="button" data-validate="submit" class="btn-primary" onclick="location=document.hop.choose.options[document.hop.choose.selectedIndex].value;" value="Calculate" style="
    margin-left: 10px;">
 </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried to resolve this and the results you are getting

Comment: Pass the value as an query string and you can read that value as `$_REQUEST['key_name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your `<head>`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_jumpMenuGo(objId,targ,restore){ //v9.0
      var selObj = null;  with (document) { 
      if (getElementById) selObj = getElementById(objId);
      if (selObj)    eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
      if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0; }
}
</script>
```

Then use this as your html form

```
<form name="form1">
    <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="./soldc.php?id=1" <?php if($_GET['id'] == 1) { ?> selected=selected <?php } ?>>Sold clienti</option>
    <option value="./soldf.php?id=2" <?php if($_GET['id'] == 2) { ?> selected=selected <?php } ?>>Sold furnizori</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Go" onClick="MM_jumpMenuGo('select','parent',0)">
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's working,  GREAT. THX A LOT ! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selection").change(function() {
            location = $("#selection option:selected").val();
        });
    });
```

Html

```
<p align="center">
    <form name="hop" class="center">
        <select name="choose" id="selection" style="width: 168px;height: 35px;">
            <option value="#">Select an option</option>
            <option value="/link1.shtml">Link 1</option>
            <option value="/link2.shtml">Link 2</option>
            <option value="/link3.shtml">Link 3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" data-validate="submit" class="btn-primary" onclick="location=document.hop.choose.options[document.hop.choose.selectedIndex].value;" value="Calculate" style="
    margin-left: 10px;">
    </form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to target page that means you the last selected option is the current page , am i correct ? use the following js code in each page :

```
 var option = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
 document.getElementById('select').value = option;
```

change this line `<select name="choose" style="width: 168px;height: 35px;">`

to this

`<select id=select name="choose" style="width: 168px;height: 35px;">`